# Collider Animating

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ok so I made an animation that moves the collider when the character flips but it takes a little.
Here is how it looks like:
[text](https://youtu.be/6bf9xeAwEfA)
If you want to ask anything like the code, the parameters I put unity.

I expect the collider to move instantly

Comment: please read [tour], [mcve] and [ask] to improve your question and more likely get a better answer

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to determine why it does not move instantly without more information, scripts, animation setup and transitions. But I would assume it is related to the animation exit time. The exit time could be stopping the animation from swapping instantly to the transition animation clip causing that short period of time before swapping.

If it is the animation exit time, you would need to go to the Animator, click the arrow going from the idle animation on either side of the character and toggle off the "*Has Exit Time*" option:

[image]

If that does not seem to work, you can always create two different colliders. One on either side of the character and whenever the character choses to flip, you can enable the collider on that side. This might cause less issues with little to no difference in the scenes performance.

If you've explored these possibilities and still can't identify the root cause, you might want to consider sharing more of your code or simplifying your setup to narrow down the issue.